# Vue Namespace Module with Params

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have my **store setup** as

```
# State
export default {
 servers: []
}
```

and my **getter** as follows

```
# Getter
export function serverById (state, id) {
 return state.servers.find(server => server.id === id)
}
```

Im **calling my getter from my vue component**

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
  //   server: 'servers/serverById'
  }),
  getServers () {
    return this.$store.getters['servers/serverById'][22]
  }
}
```

I keep getting

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook:
>   "TypeError: Cannot read property '22' of undefined"

when I change to round brackets I get

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
  //   server: 'servers/serverById'
  }),
  getServers () {
    return this.$store.getters['servers/serverById'](22)
  }
}
```

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError:
>   this.$store.getters.servers/serverById is not a function"

I have event tried using the `mapGetter` option with a method, but still no luck.

```
methods: {
  getServerDetails (id) {
    return this.server(id)
  }
}
```

Comment: export function serverById (state)  { return (id) => ....

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html look for section Method-Style Access. In a getter you need to return method that takes `id` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) look for section Method-Style Access. In a getter you need to return method that takes id argument.

```
export function serverById (state) {
 return id => state.servers.find(server => server.id === id)
}
```

and call it with 
`this.$store.getters['servers/serverById'](22)`

Answer (score 0):

Your getter should have the below format:

```
serverById : (state) => (id) => {
    return state.servers.find(server => server.id === id)
  }
```

For the namespaced module you can access getters as

```
...mapGetters('myNamespacedModule', ['myGetterName'])
```